# win32 SetDlgItemText not working from within WM_INITDIALOG

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, controls

I'm just starting to experiment with win32 and I've run into a problem.

```
BOOL CALLBACK UnsavedChangesProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
HWND dHandle = GetActiveWindow();

switch (msg)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    MessageBox(NULL, "In InitDialog", 0, 0);
    SetDlgItemText(dHandle, 1004, ("There are unsaved changes to \""));
    char error[10];
    sprintf_s(error, "%d", GetLastError());
    MessageBox(NULL, error, 0, 0);
    return TRUE;
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDSAVE:
        DoFileSave(hwnd);
        EndDialog(hwnd, TRUE);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case IDEXIT:
        EndDialog(hwnd, TRUE);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    break;
case WM_CLOSE:
    EndDialog(hwnd, FALSE);
    break;
default:
    return FALSE;
}
return TRUE;
}
```

The GetLastError() returns 1421, control ID not found, but the ID (1004) definitely corresponds to the static control I'm trying to alter. I've also tried calling the function with the control name (IDC_STATIC_UNSAVED) with no luck. The strange part is that if I move the function call to where dHandle is declared (or get rid of dHandle and just call GetActiveWindow() inside the function there) the text is changed but it flickers because the function is being called every time the message loop iterates.

Is there a simple reason that this shouldn't work that I'm missing?
Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Here is an image of the Resource Symbols: [Resource Symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEtuG.png)
      And here is an image of the Dialog Template: [Dialog Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li7ou.png)
 Note that all of the other controls work as expected.

Comment: *I'm just starting to experiment with win32* -- Advice -- the Win32 API is complex enough and shouldn't be "experimented with", unless you want to be totally frustrated that things just won't work correctly.  Get working examples from books such as Petzold or similar material.

Comment: @Paul Like any piece of computing technology, of course it should be experimented with. There is nothing in the OP's question that suggests he hasn't read the documentation; rather the reverse.

Comment: Well one thing the OP can do is load the executable into the resource editor to see if 1004 is actually a numeric resource ID instead of assuming it is an existing resource ID.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `HWND` passed to your function, rather than `GetActiveWindow()` ?  What does your dialog template look like ?  Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Also, note that focus is not set until you return `TRUE` from the `WM_INITDIALOG` handler.

Comment: @SidS The dialog is created during the WM_CLOSE message of the primary window with the DialogBox macro. I was operating with the understanding that the HWND is created at runtime and would change every time the program is run. Am I mistaken? If so, how would I find the handle? And yes, I recall that focus is not set, but I believe the dialog doesn't even become visible until WM_INITDIALOG returns true so that shouldn't be relevant in this case.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your suggestion, but I've already examined the resource editor. For completeness I edited the OP to include an image of the Resource Symbols directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: *"how would I find the handle?"*  It is the first parameter passed to your handler.  Try this: `SetDlgItemText(hwnd, 1004, "There are unsaved changes to \"");`

Comment: @SidS That worked perfectly thanks! I guess I was a little confused: I thought that SetDlgItemText needed the handle of the Dialog itself rather than the dialog of the primary window. EDIT: I now understand my mistake. All of these handles and handlers are giving me a headache. Thank you all for the prompt replies!

Comment: @SidS Also, if you'd like to add an answer for the reputation, feel free.

Comment: Don't call `GetLastError()` unless a call fails (returns a failure code), and the function is documented as setting the error code. Otherwise it's meaningless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dialog window is passed to your handler in the `hwnd` parameter.  There is no need to call `GetActiveWindow()` - in fact, that will give you the `HWND` of another window when the dialog is not the active window.

So, replace

```
HWND dHandle = GetActiveWindow();
SetDlgItemText(dHandle, 1004, ("There are unsaved changes to \""));
```

with

```
SetDlgItemText(hwnd, 1004, "There are unsaved changes to \"");
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sid S. 
Besides changing the first parameter of `SetDlgItemText` from `dHandle` to `hwnd`, I would also suggest using `IDC_STATIC_UNSAVED` instead of the hardcoded value `1004`. So, the `SetDlgItemText()` call becomes: 
`SetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_STATIC_UNSAVED, ("There are unsaved changes to \""));`